# No implicit reference conversion error

Tags: c#

I am getting the following error when using a CustomObject to instantiate my generic priority queue. It is working well when I instantiate with integer. Can anyone help me figure out the issue.

The error is appearing on line:

```
PQueue<CustomObject> pq = new PQueue<CustomObject>();
```

> Error CS0311: The type `Heap.CustomObject' cannot be used as type
>   parameter`T' in the generic type or method `Heap.PQueue<T>'. There is
>   no implicit reference conversion from`Heap.CustomObject' to
>   `System.IComparable' (CS0311) (Heap)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your generic constraint is requiring `IComparable<T>`, but your `CustomObject` only implements `IComparable`. You need to implement `IComparable<CustomObject>`

Comment: Forgive my ignorance. What is the difference between implementing `IComparable<CustomObject>` and `IComparable`.

Comment: It's a fair question :-) IComparable is not the same thing as IComparable<CustomObject>. The compiler will create a completely different type for the generic version which is what let's it be strongly typed. If you look at the IComparable method, you will see it operates with the type 'object'. While the generic version works with 'CustomObject' directly.

Comment: one other point, there's no reason you can't implement both the generic and non-generic versions of IComparable.

Comment: I made it work by changing to `where T : IComparable`. I still did not get how to implement `IComparable<CustomObject>`. I am using `IComparable' for the first time.

Comment: That works as well if that's all you need. IComparable<CustomObject> simply gives you a strongly typed method. So rather than `public int CompareTo(object obj)`, you'd have `public int CompareTo(CustomObject obj)`. This frees you from having to cast since the compiler won't let anyone pass in an object of a different type.

Comment: @Nemo In addition to implementing 'public int CompareTo(object other)', you would also implement 'public int CompareTo(CustomObject other)'. Your class declaration would be public class 'CustomObject : IComparable, IComparable<CustomObject>'