# scaffolding Error There is no implicit reference conversion from Configuration to System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration

Tags: ef-code-first, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, t4, entity-framework-6

I utuliz EF 6.0.2 Code First, VS 2013, MVC 5 and have dbContext and configuration class derived from dbMigrationConfiguratino class like this:

```
public class Db :  DbContext
    {
        public Db()
        { 
         Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Db,Migrations.Configuration -- my Derived dbMigrationConfig Classs In Migrations folder-->());
        }

        public DbSet<ItemCat> ItemCats { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public sealed class  Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Db>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        }

        protected override void Seed(Db context)
        {
        }
}
```

From here Implicit refrience conversion for From any

> class-type S to any class-type T, provided S is derived from T.

is valid. like my configuration and DbMigrationConfiguration

but when want add View for a Controller get error:

> Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> Error
>
> There was an error running the selected code generator:
>
> 'There was an error in compilation of the type 'DAL.Db'.
>
> CS0311: The type 'DAL.Migrations.Configuration'  cannot be used as
>   type parameter 'TMigrationsConfiguration' in the generic type or 
>   method
>   'System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion'.
>   **There is no implicit reference conversion from
>   'DAL.Migrations.Configuration' to
>   'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration**'.'
>
> OK

**Edit:**

find this:
[CS3011 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059384/no-implicit-reference-conversion-error)

Edit: I figure out my Db Class To :

```
    public class Db :MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DbContext,Migrations.Configuration>
    {

//Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Db,Migrations.Configuration>());
    }
```

and get same bolded above error compile time

Comment: i role back my db class to  first one and comment Database.SetInitializer() line in it. now add View for controller works